# viewpager bring current view to top

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, carousel

Im trying to make a viewpager like in this app:

[image]

All goes well, but when I set them to enough margin so they should overlap elseother, the left side is overlaping but the right side not.. 
The current view should always stay on the top overlapping the other two, but I just can't get this working.
They're fragments.

Any suggestions? There was an equel question on stackoverflow, but no answers given.

Comment: Any ideas? Still stuck on this.

Comment: Meeeh, no info to find on this, be the first one.. (Please)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this solution if you are targeting devices older than Android Lollipop. The following routine is to add in the `OnPageSelected` method of your `ViewPager` available in `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`:

```
@Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {

  //Counter for loop
  int count = 0;
  int PAGER_LOOP_THRESHOLD = 2;
  if (position >= PAGER_LOOP_THRESHOLD) {
    count = position - PAGER_LOOP_THRESHOLD;
  }
  do {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) adapter.instantiateItem(pager, count);

    if (fragment.getView() != null) {

      if (count == position) {
        fragment.getView().setElevation(8.0f);
      }
      else {
        fragment.getView().setElevation(0.0f);
      }
    }
    count++;
  } while (count < position + PAGER_LOOP_THRESHOLD);
}
```

You can use this library to achieve what you want: https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow